# Eulerian Graph with odd number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I am struggling with the following question:

Prove that for each odd integer $n ≥ 3$, there exists exactly one
Eulerian graph of order $n$ containing exactly three vertices of the
same degree and at most two vertices of any other degree.

This is how I solved this. Any feedbacks on the answer is highly appreciated:

We prove this by using induction on the graph order $n$. For $n=3$, the graph with degree sequence 2, 2, 2 is the only Eulerian graph. For $n=5$, the graph with degree sequence 4, 4, 2, 2, 2 is the only Eulerian graph. Then for $n$ odd and greater than 5, consider the sequence $n-1,\,n-1,\,d_1+2,\,d_2+2,\,\cdots,\,d_{n-4}+2,\,2,\,2$ is graphical if and only if the sequence $d_1,\,d_2,\,\cdots,\,d_{n-4},\,0,\,0$ is graphical. So, by induction, there is exactly one sequence fitting these criteria which is graphical.

Now, we check that this sequence is Eulerian. Again, by induction, we may assume that the graph $G'$, with degree sequence $d_1,\,d_2,\,\cdots,\,d_{n-4}$ is Eulerian. Let $C'$ be an Eulerian circuit in $G'$. Notice that a graph $G$ with degree sequence $n-1,\,n-1,\,d_1+2,\,d_2+2,\,\cdots,\,d_{n-4}+2,\,2,\,2$ may be constructed from $G'$ by adding four vertices $x_1,\,x_2,\,y_1,\,y_2$ and all of the edges $x_i v$ for $i=1,\,2$, and $v\in V(G')\cup \{y_1,\,y_2\}$, and the edge $x_1 x_2$. Let $v_1 v_2$ be an edge of $C'$ and let $C$ be the circuit given by:

- Follow $v_1 v_2$, then $v_2 x_1$.
- Follow the edges $x_1 v$, then $v x_2$ alternately with $x_2 u$, then $u x_1$ for all vertices $u,\,v\in V(G')\cup \{y_1,\,y_2\}-\{v_2\}$, so that each of these vertices is visited exactly once. Note that since $G$ has odd number of vertices, we visit an even number of vertices in this process, and consequently end at $x_1$.
- Follow $x_1 x_2$, then $x_2 v_2$.
- Follow the rest of $C'$.

Then $C$ is a circuit, which by construction follows every edge in $E(G)-E(G')$, and since $C'$ is an Eulerian circuit, also follows every edge in $E(G')$. Thus $C$  is an Eulerian circuit and $G$ is Eulerian.

Comment: Without thinking too deeply about the problem, my best advice would be to start trying to construct these graphs for small $n$. For instance, for $n = 3$, I can see no other way except a triangle.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your prompt response. I have tried to construct it for n = 3, 5 and 7 and always there is two vertices of degree 2 in the degree sequence. However, constructing it for any $n$ is my struggle.

Comment: What do you mean by Eulerian Graph?

Comment: @GhD A connected graph $G$ is Eulerian if all the vertices of $G$ have even degree.

Comment: @MortezaSoltani This is the kind of detail that goes very well in questions. If you can produce these graphs, it really fleshes out the question, and helps inspire people to answer. Unfortunately, I'm not in the right head space to answer at the moment, but it's a good tip nonetheless.

Comment: @GhD An Eulerian graph is a graph that admits an Euler Cycle, meaning a closed trail that uses every edge exactly once (like the "draw this shape without lifting pen off paper" problems). This is equivalent to being connected and having even degree.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you anyways for your comment. I work more on it and if I find the right solution, I will share it right here.

Comment: @TheoBendit I have solved this problem and as promised I am sharing it right here.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the order of the graph is $2k+1$, then the possible degree of each vertex is $2,4,\cdots,2k$, then by pigeonhole principle we know there are at least 3 vertice have same degree.